# tomcat6 web service call from web service methodnotfounderror

Tags: jax-ws, tomcat6

I am working on a Java Web Application that exposes a web service. This web service makes remote calls to two other java web services, on the same tomcat server. If i try to call methods from the other two services, I get a stack of errors that results in a NoSuchMethodError in the code that is automatically generated. I am using Netbeans 6.9, sun java 1.6 and apache tomcat 6.0.26. I tested the web services individually and they work fine.

Thank you for your time.

Let me be more specific

I have the RecommendationWeb web application with the RecommendationManager web service:

```
@WebService()
public class RecommendationManager {
    public ArrayList<Long> getRecommendation(long userId, int NumOfRecommendations) {
        List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = this.myHModel.getRecommendations(userId, NumOfRecommendations);
        ArrayList<Long> result = new ArrayList<Long>();
        Iterator itr = recommendations.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            RecommendedItem recItem = (RecommendedItem) itr.next();
            result.add(new Long(recItem.getItemID()));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and the ETL_Procedures web application with the ETL_WS web service:

```
@WebService()
public class ETL_WS {
    public ArrayList<Long> getCorrespondingActiveCouponsForRecommendation(ArrayList<Long> itemCategories, int numOfRecoms) {
    int sumOfAllRecommendedCategories = 0;
    Iterator itr = itemCategories.iterator();
    ArrayList<Coupon> coupons = new ArrayList<Coupon>();
    ArrayList<Long> recommendedCoupons = new ArrayList<Long>();
    HashMap productOccurences = new HashMap();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        Long item = (Long) itr.next();
        int val = 0;
        ArrayList<Coupon> temp = (ArrayList<Coupon>) couponMap.getCoupon(item);
        if(temp != null) {
            Iterator itr_a = temp.iterator();
            while(itr_a.hasNext()) {
                val += 1;
                sumOfAllRecommendedCategories += 1;
                Coupon tmp_coupon = (Coupon) itr_a.next();
                if(tmp_coupon.isActive())
                    coupons.add(tmp_coupon);
            }
            productOccurences.put(item, new Integer(val));
        }
    }
    long currentCat = coupons.get(0).getItem_id();
    int categoryRecs = 0;
    Integer currentOccurence = (Integer) productOccurences.get(new Long(currentCat));
    int maxCategoryItems = (currentOccurence.intValue()/sumOfAllRecommendedCategories);
    int tempRecItems = 0;
    int listIndex = 0;
    while(tempRecItems < numOfRecoms && listIndex < coupons.size()) {
        if(categoryRecs < maxCategoryItems && currentCat == coupons.get(listIndex).getItem_id()) {
            recommendedCoupons.add(coupons.get(listIndex).getItem_id());
            listIndex += 1;
            tempRecItems += 1;
            categoryRecs += 1;
        }else if(categoryRecs < maxCategoryItems && currentCat != coupons.get(listIndex).getItem_id()) {
            recommendedCoupons.add(coupons.get(listIndex).getItem_id());
            currentCat = coupons.get(listIndex).getItem_id();
            currentOccurence = (Integer) productOccurences.get(new Long(currentCat));
            maxCategoryItems = (currentOccurence.intValue()/sumOfAllRecommendedCategories);
            categoryRecs = 1;
            listIndex += 1;
            tempRecItems += 1;
        }else {
            recommendedCoupons.add(coupons.get(listIndex).getItem_id());
            currentCat = coupons.get(listIndex).getItem_id();
            currentOccurence = (Integer) productOccurences.get(new Long(currentCat));
            maxCategoryItems = (currentOccurence.intValue()/sumOfAllRecommendedCategories);
            categoryRecs = 1;
            listIndex += 1;
            tempRecItems += 1;
        }
    }

    return recommendedCoupons;
}
}
```

Those two methods are called within the Recommended_Interface web application from the INTERFACE_LAYER web service:

```
@WebService()
public class INTERFACE_LAYER {
    public ArrayList<Long> requestRecommendation(long userID, int noOfRecoms) {
    ArrayList<Long> recommendedCoupons = null;
    ArrayList<Long> recommendedItems = (ArrayList<Long>) getRecommendation(userID, noOfRecoms);
        recommendedCoupons = (ArrayList<Long>) getCorrespondingActiveCouponsForRecommendation(recommendedItems, noOfRecoms);
    return recommendedCoupons;
}

private static java.util.List<java.lang.Long> getRecommendation(long arg0, int arg1) {
    ws.recommender.RecommendationManagerService service = new ws.recommender.RecommendationManagerService();
    ws.recommender.RecommendationManager port = service.getRecommendationManagerPort();
    return port.getRecommendation(arg0, arg1);
}

private static java.util.List<java.lang.Long> getCorrespondingActiveCouponsForRecommendation(java.util.List<java.lang.Long> arg0, int arg1) {
    ws.etl.ETLWSService service = new ws.etl.ETLWSService();
    ws.etl.ETLWS port = service.getETLWSPort();
    return port.getCorrespondingActiveCouponsForRecommendation(arg0, arg1);
}
}
```

Comment: You may need to post a bit more detail (ie logs) in order to get a meaningful answer!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for not working was the return value of the Web Service's methods ArrayList. When I changed it to String, it worked.